# How does a monster's THAC0 in AD&D/2e relate to +Hit bonus in D&D 5th Edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, adnd-2e, conversion, attack-roll

I want to adapt several creatures from AD&D/2e so I can use them in 5e. 
Is there an easy way to translate THAC0 (to hit AC 0) to the +Hit bonus in 5e? 
I'm looking for a **formula or a chart** if possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Conversion document suggests using the HD

There is no direct one-to-one correspondence due to the "bounded accuracy" design principle of 5e. Instead of converting the THAC0, the simplest thing to do, would be to use the following method from the *[Conversion to the 5th Edition D&D](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_Conversions_1.0.pdf)* document published by the WotC:

> Attack roll modifiers are HD/2 + 2, up to +12.

---

#### Alternative make-shift attempt of converting directly from THAC0

If that is not what you want and you really desire to convert THAC0 without referring to HD or levels we can try to come up with a rough formula assuming that the to-hit bonuses progress similar to a fighter's progress.

- It is easy to convert THAC0 to the hit bonus in 3/3.5e: Simply subtract THAC0 from 20. So THAC0 of 15, would mean +5 bonus to hit.
- The fighters in 3/3.5e (as well as 2e) improved one point of hit bonus (or THAC0) for each level. In 5e, for every four levels proficiency bonus increases by one. Based on this, I would suggest something like: roundup((20-THAC0)/4)+1.
- Yet, there is one more complication: A monster's THAC0 also took into account its strength and other characteristics that the designers saw appropriate. In 2e, you cannot always figure out those details. I would suggest having at the [3.5e SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/indexes/monsters.htm) for the 3.5e version of any given monster and do a conversion using them. Conversion from 3e to 5e is probably best left to a separate question.

Comment: Hi @ZwiQ - thank you for your answer and explaining the details for 3/3.5, but that was not my question. I really appreciate the link to the Conversion and working out the + to Hit from the HD "Attack roll modifiers are HD/2 + 2, up to +12". That's really helpful and what I was looking for. Could you remove the info about 3/3.5 please so I can close the question. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @ETgothome: I have restructured the answer to make the conversion document method the main answer. If you don't mind, I do not want to delete the alternative as some people have already voted positively seeing only that part and I would feel bad to completely change the answer after those votes. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks @ZwiQ, you're a legend.

Answer (score 4):

So a very oversimplified way to do a THACO to 5e conversion is to just consider "0" in THACO as an AC of 20. As in 2e rules without any kind of attack modifiers (aka +0 to hit) you need to roll a 20 to hit an AC of 0.

So a THACO of -2 would be an AC of 22 and a THACO of 2 would be an AC of 18.   You'll find for the most part its a "roughly right" conversion which you can tweak from there for your own sense of balance for that particular NPC or Monster.

So if your character has a +6 to hit then their THAC0 is 14.   If your character has a +15 to hit then their THAC0 is 5.   Again this is a "roughly right" conversion.  A great Welsh builder once told me "Better to be roughly right then precisely wrong"  I feel that pertains fairly accurately to this case. Again if after doing this simple conversion you still don't feel it's right you can adjust up or down from there.

I have an example of a conversion of the demon lord Graz'zt in the comments below from his 2e stats as I found his 5e stats Woefully low in certain aspects having fought him in the past while playing 2e. (note: when I say "tracks with 5e" in the comments below it refers to how accurate the New AC/ + to hit bonus feels after conversion from what it was in 2e using the logic above.)

Comment: It would really improve this answer if you included some calculations that demonstrated the parallel that you are asserting.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE! Agreed with Thomas-- I believe I've seen this line of thinking elsewhere, but some extra support is definitely needed for this answer.

Comment: well without any kind of bonus to attack modifiers an AC of 0 in 2e required a 20 to hit.  Hence it's essentially an AC of 20.   So once you figure that out you can calculate what the attack bonus is from there using 5e rules.  If you're character has a +6 to hit then your "THAC0" is essentially 14.   When you see a 2e monster with an AC of -3 you know it's AC is functionally 23.

Comment: @SkullMonkey I've got it now, the examples were helpful.

Comment: Gald I could help.  Like I said it's a decent "rough" conversion.  Like I'm doing a conversion of demon lord Graz'zt from some of his 2e Stats in "For Duty and Diety" and in that he has a THAC0 of 4 (which is a +16 to hit which tracks with 5e) and an armor class of -9 which  which is a ridiculously difficult AC to hit for 2e but that does make sense for an AC of 29 so again it tracks.  It also kind of makes sense as he's A) a Demon Lord and B) always had a giant tower shield to pair with his wave of sorrow in 2e.    But if you feel that's too hard you can tweak his AC down to say 25 or 26.

Comment: @SkullMonkey The [official 5e Graz'zt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/grazzt) has an AC of 20 and +13 to hit. The mighty Tarrasque only has an AC of 25.

Comment: Right which again I feel is just woefully low.  I fought him several times in the past when I used to play 2e long ago and one of his signature aspects was how difficult he was to hit. Like obnoxiously so. I can absolutely guarantee a -9 AC in 2e does not equate to an AC of 20 in 5e because again in 2e it took a 20 to hit AC 0 with no modifiers.  -9 is a bananna pants hard AC to hit for 2e so an AC of 29 fits that.  As for his to hit bonus again +13 seems woefully low for a Demon Lord w/ 22 STR wielding an Legendary weapon.  A level 13 fighter with 18 STR and a +2 longsword has a +11 to hit.